# Problem With Internet Under Easy Peasy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, internet, home-networking

I have an Eee PC 904D that i use for development, because it's tiny and little, but i have a PC too. But in my Eee PC that i have Ubuntu Intrepid Ibex with the Netbook Remix(Easy Peasy), when i want to use the ethernet cable for the internet i connect it and tryes to connect, but in aproximatly 10 secs trying to connect it fails and change the icon like i don't put any cable, but the cable is connected and other computers when i try to use this cable connect normally, if is needed here is the content of /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf file:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

send host-name "<hostname>";
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
```

Here is the ifconfig log:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:15:a2:6a:8f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:220 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1880 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:1880 (1.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:af:eb:d8:6e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:afff:feeb:d86e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3216735 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:1377796 (1.3 MB)

wmaster0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-15-AF-EB-D8-6E-38-36-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried network-manager? Network manager doesn't use dhclient.conf. You can find its configuration under /etc/NetworkManager but it's best done using the configuration dialogs.

Comment: I'm using the network-manager!

Answer (score 1):

Does it get an IP address? type "ifconfig" in a console and look for an address for eth0. If it gets an IP address, try to ping another machine by its IP.

Comment: Now i put the ifconfig log, but if i connect the same cable in my PC, it gets the ip and all ok, and in my notbook, in every place that i put a cable on it i have this error.

Comment: Try this : connect the cable, then from a shell do "sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart" to reload your network configuration. That should work.